# Can I limit the results of a query in dynamoDB based on the sum of attributes?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Suppose I have a dynamo table with the following attributes

```
InventoryLot {
   SKU  //Partition Key
   ShipmentDateTime, //Sort Key
   ItemQuantity, 
   ShipmentID,
}
```

Is there a way to efficiently limit the number of items whose ItemQuantity add up to an amount?

| SKU | TimeStamp | Quantity | DocID|

| A1 | Jan 01 00:00:01| 10 | ID1 |

| A1 | Jan 02 00:00:00 | 10 | ID2 |

| A2 | Jan 03 00:00:00 | 5. | ID3 |

|A!1 | Jan 04 00:00:00. | 10 | ID4|

|A1 | Jan 05 00:00:00. | 10| ID5|

For example, suppose this is my table, I want to get the 25 oldest items where SKU eq A1, does dynamoDB support this type of query? Since DDB is a key-value store it doesn't seem like it but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the results of a query based on the value of an attribute, but there is no way to generate the aggregation "on the fly" with the query operation.  In other words, there is no aggregation operation in DynamoDB analogous to SQL aggregate operations (e.g. sum/avg/count).

The best way to do this in DynamoDB is to maintain the count as you insert/remove items to the table.  You can then use that aggregated value to create conditional operations (e.g. put, update, etc).